# how to access any element In nested objects in js

Tags: javascript, object

```
popup_data = {
    club: {
        type: 'club',
        type_img: {
            header: 'CLUB HEADER',
            img: 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600',
            sub_header: 'CLUB SUB HEADER',
            content: 'TEXT',
            hotspot_position: [5, -1.5, 2.5]
        },
        hotspots_array: [
            {   id: () => this.club.type + '-' + 'type_img',
                position: () => this.club.type_img.hotspot_position,
            },
        ]   
    },
```

How to get type and type_img.hotspot_position from these nested functions

Comment: thanks to all guys finally I got the solutions, problem was arrow function , arrow functions doest support this keyword, so I used normal function then I worked

Answer (score 0):

```
let postion = popup_data.club.type_img.hotspot_position

let type = popup_data.club.type
```

Comment: Still error output : TypeError: undefined is not an object

Comment: you must be trying to use the value when its either not set, (before being set) or after the scope might have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access type with `popup_data.club.type` and hotspot_position with `popup_data.club.type_img.hotspot_position`

Comment: unfortunately not working bro well thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot notation

```
console.log(popup_data.club.type_img.hotspot_position)
```

or you can also use map to print each item separately

```
popup_data.club.type_img.hotspot_position.map( item => console.log(item) );
```

Comment: don't know why its not working , getting only TypeError: undefined is not an object error. well thanks bro for your help anyway

Comment: Your object popup_data must be before above code.